# cs50 pset1 greedy unusual bug

Tags: c, greedy, cs50

---

My code for the greedy programme works fine for all numbers so far except for    4.2 . 
Would really appreciate it if anyone can point out the error

```
:) greedy.c exists
:) greedy.c compiles
:) input of 0.41 yields output of 4
:) input of 0.01 yields output of 1
:) input of 0.15 yields output of 2
:) input of 1.6 yields output of 7
:) input of 23 yields output of 92
**:( input of 4.2 yields output of 18
   \ expected output, but not "22\n"**
:) rejects a negative input like -.1
:) rejects a non-numeric input of "foo"
:) rejects a non-numeric input of ""
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
   float x;
  do
 {
     printf("how much change is owed(in dollars)?:\n");
     x = GetFloat();
 }
  while (x < 0);


  x = x*100;
  int i = 0;
 while (x >= 25)
 {
    x = (x-25);
    i++;
 }


  while (x >= 10)
 {
    x = (x-10);
    i++;
 }

 while (x >= 5)
 {
    x = (x-5);
    i++;
 }

 while (x >= 1)
 {
    x = (x-1);
    i++;
 }
 printf("%d\n",i);
}
```

Comment: Please see [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). Better, work with `int` values. There are numerous "change" questions on SO which exhibit this problem. So far from being "unusual" it is a stage you go through.

Comment: Never use floating point if you need precise values.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line

`x = x*100;`

into

`x = floor(x*100);
printf("rounded value: %f\n", x);`

It will print `rounded value: 419` and for that 22 is the right answer.
(16x25 + 1x10 + 1x5 + 4x1)

That's what's happening now, as the value that is stored in `x` is close to 420 but a little bit smaller.

Answer (score 0):

This bug has to do with the floating point imprecision, run the following code and you see what's really happening under the hood:

```
float x = 4.2;
printf("%.50f\n", x);
```

So instead it's best to first convert the value to a positive integer corresponding to the full value of cents (remember that $4.2 is the same of 420 cents), and do the calculations with this value (and don't forget to round the value first).

Answer (score 0):

There is always an imprecision in float numbers. Therefore it is recommended that we convert `float` to `int`. You can do so by
`int amount = lroundf(change*100);` also note that the value is multiplied by a 100 times. This is to get rid of the cents, and then round off those unwanted values using the 'lroundf' command.